# Spring boot application Post method invocation, 405: Method Not Allowed

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I am writing Rest Application with Spring boot. To expose my service code in as REST services.

I am able to expose my services in GET method when I am writing Post method with below code of Controller and Pojo class I am getting  405: Method Not Allowed error. 
Not able to understand why ?

I have refered this [link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32479919/spring-boot-405-post-method-not-supported) and others related too but i could not figure out what is the problem.

Below is my controller and Pojo with jackson Json annotated code.

When i am calling using [Advanced REST client - Chrome Web Store - Google](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo) and using as [attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5DJgb.jpg) i am getting below error.

In the  same class i have some GET method that is working fine. 
Error : 
 URL : `http://localhost:8085/DBService/application/saveApplicationAnswer`

```
{
"timestamp": 1470313096237
"status": 405
"error": "Method Not Allowed"
"exception": "org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException"
"message": "Request method 'POST' not supported"
"path": "/DBService/application/saveApplicationAnswer"
}
```

`DBService` is my Context Name

As I have set `server.context-path=/DBService` in `application.properties`

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.drd.hotel.db.service.IApplicationDBService;
import com.drd.hotel.db.service.dto.application.CustomerDTO;
import com.drd.hotel.db.service.dto.application.ApplicationAnswerDTO;
import com.drd.hotel.db.service.dto.application.ApplicationQuestionsDTO;
import com.drd.hotel.db.service.dto.application.ApplicationRecommendationDTO;
import com.drd.hotel.db.service.util.ServicesConstants;

  @RestController
@RequestMapping("/application")
public class ApplicationDBController<T, I extends Serializable> {

    @Autowired
    private IApplicationDBService applicationDBService;



    @RequestMapping(value = "/saveApplicationAnswer", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public int saveApplicationAnswer(@ModelAttribute(ServicesConstants.SURVERY_ANSWER_FL) ApplicationAnswerDTO applicationAnswer) {

        LOG.info("ApplicationDBController fn saveApplicationAnswer BookingId {} {} {}",applicationAnswer.getBookingId(),  ServicesConstants.CUSTOMER_ID_FL, applicationAnswer.getCustomerId());
        return applicationDBService.saveapplicationAnswer(applicationAnswer);
    }

}
```

My JSON:

```
{"answerId":1,"applicationQuestionId":1,"recommendId":1,"bookingId":123001,"customerId":19501,"reasonForCancelation":"I dont konw ","feedbackText":"I dont know what is this too bad design","applicationDate":"2016-08-04","funnelPageName":"I dont know what is the use of this.","applicationReferenceSource":"I dont knwo what is this field for","languageId":1}
```

**MY Pojo annotated with JSON :**

```
import java.util.Date;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect.Visibility;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize.Inclusion;




    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    @JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = Visibility.ANY, getterVisibility = Visibility.NONE, setterVisibility = Visibility.NONE)
    @JsonSerialize(include =Inclusion.NON_NULL)

    public class ApplicationAnswerDTO {

        private int answerId;
        private int applicationQuestionId;
        private int recommendId;
        private int bookingId;
        private int customerId;
        private String reasonForCancelation;
        private String feedbackText;
        private Date applicationDate;
        private String funnelPageName;
        private String applicationReferenceSource;
        private int languageId;

        public int getAnswerId() {
            return answerId;
        }
        public void setAnswerId(int answerId) {
            this.answerId = answerId;
        }
        public int getApplicationQuestionId() {
            return applicationQuestionId;
        }
        public void setApplicationQuestionId(int applicationQuestionId) {
            this.applicationQuestionId = applicationQuestionId;
        }
        public int getRecommendId() {
            return recommendId;
        }
        public void setRecommendId(int recommendId) {
            this.recommendId = recommendId;
        }
        public int getBookingId() {
            return bookingId;
        }
        public void setBookingId(int bookingId) {
            this.bookingId = bookingId;
        }
        public int getCustomerId() {
            return customerId;
        }
        public void setCustomerId(int customerId) {
            this.customerId = customerId;
        }

        public String getFeedbackText() {
            return feedbackText;
        }
        public void setFeedbackText(String feedbackText) {
            this.feedbackText = feedbackText;
        }
        public Date getApplicationDate() {
            return applicationDate;
        }
        public void setApplicationDate(Date applicationDate) {
            this.applicationDate = applicationDate;
        }
        public String getFunnelPageName() {
            return funnelPageName;
        }
        public void setFunnelPageName(String funnelPageName) {
            this.funnelPageName = funnelPageName;
        }
        public String getApplicationReferenceSource() {
            return applicationReferenceSource;
        }
        public void setApplicationReferenceSource(String applicationReferenceSource) {
            this.applicationReferenceSource = applicationReferenceSource;
        }
        public int getLanguageId() {
            return languageId;
        }
        public void setLanguageId(int languageId) {
            this.languageId = languageId;
        }

        public String getReasonForCancelation() {
            return reasonForCancelation;
        }
        public void setReasonForCancelation(String reasonForCancelation) {
            this.reasonForCancelation = reasonForCancelation;
        }
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "ApplicationAnswerDTO [answerId=" + answerId + ", applicationQuestionId="
                    + applicationQuestionId + ", recommendId=" + recommendId
                    + ", bookingId=" + bookingId + ", customerId=" + customerId
                    + ", reasonForCancelation="
                    + reasonForCancelation + ", feedbackText="
                    + feedbackText + ", applicationDate=" + applicationDate
                    + ", funnelPageName=" + funnelPageName
                    + ", applicationReferenceSource=" + applicationReferenceSource
                    + ", languageId=" + languageId + "]";
        }


    }
```

[image]

Thanks in advance for any kind of info and suggestion.

Comment: how  are you calling this? any rest client or code?

Comment: As I have attached image of rest client,I am calling using URL  of post method. 
and put Json input of my pojo class in raw Payload section.

Comment: error usually arises that when you are calling like 'POST' method on 'GET' supported method, recheck whether you are calling the right method

Answer (score 1):

```
Can you check the method type which your are requesting.
In the screen shot which your shared it is displaying only get and head method are allowed.
I have tried your code in my Soap ui. It is displaying the below response.

HTTP/1.1 200 
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Thu, 04 Aug 2016 13:03:11 GMT

1999999999



It is displaying the response which you shared when i try to call the same service using Get method.Below is the response.

    {
       "timestamp": 1470315684018,
       "status": 405,
       "error": "Method Not Allowed",
       "exception": "org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException",
       "message": "Request method 'GET' not supported",
       "path": "/saveApplicationAnswer"
    }
```

and code I used is

```
  {
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveApplicationAnswer", method =        RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces =  MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public int saveApplicationAnswer(@ModelAttribute("hello")   ApplicationAnswerDTO applicationAnswer) {
    System.out.println(applicationAnswer);
    return 1999999999;
    }
```

Please try with different tools preferably soap ui.

Answer (score 1):

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/saveApplicationAnswer", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
  public int saveApplicationAnswer(@RequestBody(ServicesConstants.SURVERY_ANSWER_FL) ApplicationAnswerDTO applicationAnswer) {

            LOG.info("ApplicationDBController fn saveApplicationAnswer BookingId {} {} {}",applicationAnswer.getBookingId(),  ServicesConstants.CUSTOMER_ID_FL, applicationAnswer.getCustomerId());
            return applicationDBService.saveapplicationAnswer(applicationAnswer);
        }
```

I have changed my parameter annotation refering [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30309348/java-spring-restcontroller-post).

From

```
@ModelAttribute(ServicesConstants.SURVERY_ANSWER_FL) ApplicationAnswerDTO applicationAnswer
```

To

```
@RequestBody(ApplicationAnswerDTO applicationAnswer
```

It worked for me. seems `@RequestBody` is  correct. But i dont know the different between `@RequestBody` and `@ModelAttribute`. If any one knows the different please share here. That will be helpful for some one.

When i am pitting `@RequestBody(ApplicationAnswerDTO applicationAnswer)`  It worked for me.

**Any way Thanks for every one for your help and suggestion.**